# Create legacy fallback for pixi.js

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

So far I've been using `pixi.js` for all of my import:

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js"
```

Using another computer though, it returns the following error:

> WebGl unsupported in this browser, use "pixi.js-legacy" for fallback canvas2d support.

But how do I do so? Documentation says that one's supposed to import PIXI like that using legacy:

```
import * as PIXI from "pixi.js-legacy"
```

But I've also read that using it once, it will always make pixi.js use the legacy.

**Do I just use `pixi.js-legacy` from the very beginning for all of my import or is there another approach to create such a callback in case of disparities?**

Comment: Yes, if you want to support old browsers (without WebGl) then you should use `pixi.js-legacy`. If you use it then it fallbacks to software rendering if WebGl is not supported by browser.

Comment: @domis86 But using it won't come with any disadvantages for modern browsers?

Comment: AFAIK no - is just a bit heavier (bigger files - more code etc). But if you really want to support also old browsers then you should keep it in mind during development of your application and perform tests which will ensure that your app is working on said old browsers. By tests i mean manual tests (for example as you mentioned: running your app in "another computer" browser where there is no WebGL support and checking if all features are working OK) and automatic tests (for example: via headless Chrome with WebGl support turned off etc, or Selenium)